# Handling single .ads files when building Ada with SCons

Tags: dependencies, ada, scons, gnat, build-system

How do I adapt the `scons-gnat` and `scons-ada` builder to work with ads-files that don't have a corresponding .adb file? I ask because `gnatbind` asks for ali-files corresponding to .ads files when no corresponding .adb is present.

I need this because in our organisation some modules are delivered in binary format (`.ads`, `.ali` and `.o` only). I've also heard something about making the .ali files readonly to make the gnat suite happier.

If you help out with this I could finally convince the leaders in my IT-organisation to make the switch from Make to Scons. This will gives enormous increase of compilation speed and iterative development joy thanks to all the cool features of SCons including shared caching, explicit environment handling etc.

Comment: Is this the `scons-gnat` posted on Github by terazini? I wish they had first imported the original `scons-ada` source and then made their changes! Anyway, (a) yes, you should make the `.ali` files read-only, (b) `.adb` files are needed sometimes - for example, for generics, (c) `scons-gnat` is seriously misconceived; the GNAT compilation process is much too complex for a sensible person to try to second-guess `gnatmake -c`.

Comment: If then I wonder...should the ali files corresponding to the single .ads files be put under version control or not? If not SCons needs to generate these...and from what I've seen so far scons-ada doesn't not do this (yet).

Comment: Could you give some clues as to where to add functionality in scons-ada for building single `.ads` files to `.ali` and `.o` files? I believe this is a bit tricky to express in the current form of Builders right? Because the scons builder api is not flexible enough for this behaviour: Only build an .ads if it to does not have a corresponding adb file. You can't express this with traditional wildcard matchers. Is an SCons `Emitter` the solution?

Comment: @SimonWright. I'm using `scons-ada`, btw. The `scons-gnat` didn't work me.

Comment: Is that the `scons-ada` posted on code.google.com by rotinom? (and when you say `scons-add` in your question, do you actually mean `scons-ada`? Anyway, I don't know `scons` (being quite happy with `make`), so at the moment I can't "help" further ...

Comment: I meant scons-ada. Sorry for the typo.